# What is the proper way to use a runnable to start a threaded client socket in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client

I'm trying to start a new client connection in my TCP P2P program. I want to start each new connection on a runnable.

I'm not sure what the issue is. The program doesn't break or anything. It's like it just ignores the code for starting a thread.

*update*
The following code connects but immediately terminates program.

```
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                       try {
                            Socket socketClient = new Socket(ip, yPort);
                        } catch(Exception ec){
                            System.out.println("error" + ec);
                        } 
                    }
                };
                
                clientThread.start();
                System.out.println("connected to " + portName);
```

Comment: You are not starting a thread. You are creating an anonymous instance of the `Runnable` interface, nothing else. You need do something like `new Thread(thread).start();`

Comment: Thanks! I'll get on that now.

Comment: Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Not exactly, but this should work. Does it?

Comment: It does connect. The example I found online didn't have a ';' after the final bracket but it wouldn't work for me without it so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Correction, this connects. But it ends the program immediately.

Comment: What else do you expect? You create a thread that connects, then it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you just connect inside of thread and then there is nothing to do , so jvm process end and all sockets and allocated memory will be free then !